# Command not found error while trying to run imagemagick from within IDLE

Tags: python, macos, subprocess, imagemagick, python-idle

I want to do some ImageMagick stuff through Python and I have ImageMagick installed on my Mac OS. When I run my code from within Python IDLE, it gives me `/bin/sh: magick: command not found` error while running the same program through terminal works fine. For example, when I run it like `sh-3.2$ python3 imageMagicProblems.py` from terminal, there is no issue.

Can someone help me understand why the problem happens when run through Python IDLE? See attached [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wo2lO.png) also.

Here is my code:

```
import subprocess

args = "magick -version"
p = subprocess.Popen(args, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
(out, err) = p.communicate()
print (out.decode('utf-8').rstrip())
print (err.decode('utf-8').rstrip())
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your environment is different, specifically your `PATH`. In order to find the full path to your `magick` command, go in your normal Terminal where `magick` works and run:

```
type magick
```

and it will tell you something like:

```
magick is
/usr/local/bin/magick
```

Now in your Python `subprocess` command, use that same full path you found, e.g.

```
args = '/usr/local/bin/magick -version'
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked but I still don't understand the difference it caused. When I say `shell = True` shouldn't it be working using the same PATH as I run it through terminal directly? 

If I switch my shell to `/bin/sh` or `/bin/bash` and say 'magick' it works.